# Obtener localización de usuario y cambiar moneda según su país

Tags: php, wordpress, php7, wordpress-plugin, geolocalización

Buenas tengo un custom post type dónde ofrezco un cursó el precio está en dólares... Pero quisiera cambiar la moneda según la ubicación de la persona que visita estuve pensando algo así

$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] : ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$res = file_get_contents('https://www.iplocate.io/api/lookup/'.$ip);
$res = json_decode($res);

var_dump($res);

Y guardarla en un caché con

setcookie('nombreCookie', $res);

Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para jugar con esos valores en especial el país y asignar la moneda según la persona que visite mi página

Answer (score 0):

Averiguar des de dónde esta entrando el usuario es muy complicado si no se utiliza un script para obtener su geolocalización, pues con el método que intentas hacerlo a través de la IP podría ser que el usuario este utilizando un proxy que cambie la IP y por lo tanto el país de origen.

Podrías hacerlo dependiendo del idioma del navegador que esta utilizando el usuario con PHP.

```
$idioma = locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);

if ($idioma = 'es_ES') {
    // €
}
```